# Wildfly jboss ssl configuration with windows-my or windows-root

Tags: jboss, wildfly

How to configure wildfly jboss with a DNS named cert like myapp.mydomain.com installed in windows-my keystore.

I have added sunMSCAPI module as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that should work as any other keystore type. Make sure proper security providet is installed in java. And use proper keystore type.

I recommend to use Elytron for that.